# How to add script for generate flags into Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm learning **llvm** with its official tutorial. The problem I met is that if I use shell directly to compile c++ files to link with llvm libraries, it's very convenient to have **llvm-config** to generate the correct flags and paths for me. Like this one:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core
```

But I would like to use **Xcode** to debug my c++ code. So how can I add the script above to **Xcode** to generate the paths and flags?

Comment: with xcode you can just make a project and then run it in debug mode.  You don't have to set debug flags yourself.

Comment: @xaxxon it's not debug flags. It's compile flags, compile flags, link flags, link flags, etc. Without these the project using llvm cannot compile.

Comment: you just don't have to set any flags to anything to use xcode with the system version of clang to compile C++ code.

Comment: @xaxxon Have you ever try compile c++ code with llvm in Xcode?( By "with llvm" I mean using llvm's API) If not, don't comment on things you don't understand please.

Comment: not sure if you're trying to be rude or not (but it comes across that way), but I'm answering your question.   xcode uses llvm to compile c++.   it can't use anything else.   What API are you referring to with which you would compile C++?

Comment: @xaxxon I'm not talking the llvm that Xcode uses to compile c++, I'm talking the llvm library code I want to use in my c++ code. I would apologize if my rude words hurt you, but clearly you never compile c++ code with llvm libraries before :( .

Comment: "clearly you never compile c++ code with llvm libraries" Nope, never heard of it.  https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit/blob/master/class_parser/CMakeLists.txt#L12  I use cmake, which can generate xcode projects.  Also, a more clear description of what you want to do is "link against the llvm libraries".

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks. I have update the question, sorry for the inaccurate description. It seems using cmake is the best option for me.